# asp.net mvc (use external dll of c++ Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E )

Tags: c++, asp.net, opencv, model-view-controller, dll

I write a asp.net mvc project, this project use external dll of c++ (ACTR_DLL.dll) this project run on my system successfully. But when get publish from visual studio, external dll of c++ dont exist in folders 
when i upload project on server, this error is shown:

> Unable to load DLL 'ACTR_DLL.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details:

> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'ACTR_DLL.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

i replace external dll of c++ in folder in server but error dont solved

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using ?

Comment: visual studio 2017 Enterprise

Comment: Perhaps you can refer to the following link. Seems to be a known issue which has been fixed too: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/96746/visual-studio-153-publish-aspnet-web-projects-will.html

Comment: i add external dll in new folder and set true address in source code
set address is true , but show error : 
 Unable to load DLL 'C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/FolderDll/dll/ACTR_DLL.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Answer (score 0):

In addition you should check that no dependencies of your dll is missing. For that you can use the Dependencies tool: https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies

Then from there you should be able to take the appropriate actions.